# WindowLess WinForm or Console app to launch .bat files?

Tags: winforms, console-application

I want to launch a .bat file through a scheduler. The .bat file calls a third party command line tool. What's the difference between doing this through a console app vs a windowless winform application? I am using .NET. I prefer the app not show a DOS window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a windows scheduled task.  I assume that you're using the ProcessStart classes to launch the program from .NET?  If so then I think the only difference would be the overhead involved in the WinForm assemblies being loaded vs not loading in the console app.